# how to redirect proparly after google log-in using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-api, codeigniter-3, google-signin, tempdata

I have a Codeigniter website,

I'm tring to redirect users to different URLs after logging-in with google log-in dependent on the button they click before.

i set an "Authorised redirect URI" in google APIs.

i tried to set tempdata before the user log-in but it wont work, even seting userdata isn't working.
what is the proper way? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use session while login with social media rather use database to keep data for temporary use. Authorization sometimes destroys sessions.